# How to read text from clipboard?

Tags: linux, x11, copy-paste

Is that possible to read text from clipboard on Linux udner X?
I select some text in a browser (Firefox for example) then click Edit->Copy.
Now I need this text in my application. I am using plain XLib. No GTK, no QT.
I do not want to use external apps like `xsel`. I studiet `xsel` source code, DAMN it is over 1000 lines. In Windows I am used to `GetCLipboardTextW()` one function call. That's all I need. Why is this so sophisticated? I have read this already:

http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_12.html

And some more, I know there are many kinds of clipboards in X, selections, cut buffers etc. It does not help! Give me some code that compiles and works. No external libraries please no sudo apt-get install something, no "Are you using KDE(GNOME/whatever)?".

Comment: In X11 we normally use external libraries a.k.a. toolkits. That's the mode of work X was designed for. Writing against raw X is an exception, not the norm, and is best reserved for X experts.

Comment: yes that's what I want, an expert advice, is SO a place to ask for one?

Answer (score 0):

[xclip](http://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xclip.c) is just 600 lines of code, but much of it seems to be due to processing command line options, reading input files, etc. Looking at `main` and `doOut` the core of what it does seems to be:

```
XOpenDisplay(...)
XCreateSimpleWindow(...)
XSelectInput(...)
XFetchBuffer(...) or xcout(...)
XCloseDisplay(...)
```

Comment: I waslooking at xsel here https://github.com/kfish/xsel/blob/master/xsel.c which is 2226 lines

Comment: sad news, xlcip.c relies on `Xmu` which means it is not pure X11?